# Generic method to get enum associated with value?

Tags: typescript

Was trying to write a utility function which takes an enum and value as inputs and returns the enum member having that value as the return value.

that is if you had enum

```
enum Fruits {
  Apples = "apple",
  Pears = "pear",
  Grapes = "grape"
}
```

Can I write a function that looks something like `enumFromVal<Fruits>("apple")` returns `Fruits.Apples`?

Theoretically something that looks sort of like this:

```
export const enumFromVal = function<T extends enum>(val : string | number ) : T {
    let vals = T.values();
    let index = vals.indexOf(val);
    let keys = T.keys();
    return keys[index];
}
```

But of course that doesn't compile, because, I guess enum isn't a type.

Comment: Enum values are just strings/numbers at runtime.  `Fruits.Apples === "apple"` at runtime; they're the same.  So the *implementation* of `enumFromVal` would just be `return val;`.  The TypeScript *type checker* treats `Fruits.Apples` as being something more specific than `"apple"`.  If you care about the *type* returned from `enumFromVal()` you can do something like [this](//tsplay.dev/WKqBzN) for string enums anyway.  But this is a weird thing to want; enums are ideally used when the actual value should be opaque to the TS user...

Comment: You might be better off just using a `const` object [as mentioned here](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#objects-vs-enums) and not make the TS compiler fight itself.  That is, just use `"apple"` as the type. You can still have an object named `Fruits` where `Fruits.Apples === "apple"` if you want it.  --- Does this address your question fully?  If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: To put what @jcalz is saying another way, TypeScript's types are erased at runtime (unlike C#'s).  So you can't implicitly pass around types using generics, you have to explicitly pass them around using parameters.  So `enumFromValue<T>(value: any): T { /* anything using T in _value_ space here won't work */ }` isn't going to cut it.  Instead, you need a signature that approximates `enumFromValue<T>(enumClass: T, value: keyof T | T[keyof T]): T`.  However, `extends enum` isn't real TypeScript because `enum` is itself erased at runtime, where it is just an ordinary object.

Comment: #jcals, The thing I was trying to do which may be a fools errand is to have 2-way mapping from enum key to enum value and back.  Particularly when enum values are exported say to JSON, indexes can be tedious unless you have easy access to the defintion and the json doc becomes unintelligible on its own.  But when you reimport the json doc it seems harder than expected to map a string value back to the enum member it comes from.  Like if you have a value like "paid_current" that comes from an enum like InvoiceStatus {Paid = "paid_current"}. sort of thing.